How to make circular waveform video with background image using ffmpeg?
Hi I want to make a circular waveform video using ffmpeg but want to use the background image. I tried this command many times but didn't work, I tried using ChatGPT over and over but didn't work at all now I'm questioning whether is it even possible to make it in a single command or not.
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i background.png -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=size=100x100:colors=white:draw=full:mode=p2p[v];[v]format=rgba,geq='p(mod((2*W/(2*PI))*(PI+atan2(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2)),W), H-2*hypot(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2))'[vout];[1:v][vout]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4

I used this command without bg it works:

ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=size=100x100:colors=white:draw=full:mode=p2p[v]; \[v]format=rgba,geq='p(mod((2*W/(2*PI))*(PI+atan2(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2)),W), H-2*hypot(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2))'[vout]" -map "[vout]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4



In this case, the geq filter needs the alpha parameter and the equation you wrote to calculate the transparency of pixels.
[v]format=rgba,geq='p(mod((2*W/(2*PI))*(PI+atan2(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2)),W), H-2*hypot(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2))':a='1*alpha(mod((2*W/(2*PI))*(PI+atan2(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2)),W), H-2*hypot(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2))'[vout]; // here


Full command:
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i background.png -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=size=100x100:colors=white:draw=full:mode=p2p[v];[v]format=rgba,
geq='p(mod((2*W/(2*PI))*(PI+atan2(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2)),W), H-2*hypot(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2))':a='1*alpha(mod((2*W/(2*PI))*(PI+atan2(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2)),W), H-2*hypot(0.5*H-Y,X-W/2))'[vout];[1:v][vout]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4


OMG! This is super works! Big Big thanks!
